# How can i navigate to URLs with Select?

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu

I want to navigate on an site with a select box. When a user change the select-option, it opened the url of this option.

This is my select:

```
<select id="navigation">
   <option value="/" selected>start</option>
   <option value="/thoughts">thoughts</option>
   <option value="/work">work</option>
   <option value="/methods">methods</option>
</select>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
document.getElementById("navigation").onchange = function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  window.location.href = "http://niklasjordan.com" + selectedOption;
}
```

But this code doesnt work. Anybody an idea why?

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: Probably you are calling this function before dom is ready.

Comment: so we need to see more of your code - `document.getElementById("navigation")` returns null

Comment: Yep, if your code is in your head section (possibly through an external js file), it will be executed before your select is placed in the DOM.

Comment: Are you trying to bind the onClick method to the element before it is rendered? This would explain the null as it can't find it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, guys!

The solution was very simple: i put my code from the head before the closed body tag. Voilá! It run...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming You're using vanilla Javascript, put your code inside this function:

```
var domReady = function(callback) {
    document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete" ? callback() : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
};

domReady(function() {
    document.getElementById("navigation").onchange = function() {
        var selectedOption = this.value;
        window.location.href = "http://niklasjordan.com" + selectedOption;
    }
});
```

(This only works on IE9 and above)

Short explanation: You have to wait your DOM fully loaded before manipulation it!