# How to make dropdown list with button and navigate to another page

Tags: php, html

I require guidance on how to code dropdown list that can navigate to another page.
For example, dropdown list have Youtube, Google, Facebook. If user choose YouTube in dropdownlist, upon click "submit" button. The page will go to YouTube.

I use switch case php with echo " location.href='https://www.google.com'" but the upon click submit. It didn't respond.

```
<select id="dropwdown1" name="dropdown" disabled="true">
    form method="post" action="?">  
        <option disabled selected="select">---Select Web---</option>
        <option value="1">YouTube</option>
        <option value="2">Google</option>
        <option value="3">Facebook</option>
</select>
            
<input type="submit" value="SELECT">
</form>
<?php
switch ($_POST['dropdown'])  { 
    case "1": 
        echo "<script> location.href='https://www.youtube.com'</script>";
        exit;
}
case "2": 
    echo "<script> location.href='https://www.google.com'</script>";
    exit;
}
case "3": 
    echo "<script> location.href='https://www.facebook.com'</script>";
    exit;
} ?>
```

Comment: This is not Java

Comment: @JayC667 sorry, i thought <script> was actually java

Comment: After I've removed the excess spacing from your snippet, do you see how horribly broken it is?  Tabbing your code properly is an important part of being a good programmer and eliminating silly mistakes -- like writing a broken form tag inside of a select tag.

Comment: [Potentially relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5150363/2943403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36528708/2943403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12388954/2943403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33419682/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

First Time writing an answer in stackoverflow but I think instead of writing  Youtube Directly you add like a link inside the Option so something like this `<option value="1"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="__blank">Youtube</a> </option>`
I am not sure if this is what you were trying to say but yea

Comment: Does this open a new page when the option is selected or after the form is submitted?